# Following a course and mongoose keeps throwing invalid schema error. Original code was built in mongoose 5.8.7 but no longer works in current version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, server, mongoose-schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const crypto = require("crypto");

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    hashed_password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "user",
    },
    resetPasswordLink: {
      data: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// virtual fields
userSchema
  .virtual("password")
  .set(function (password) {
    // create temp variable called _password
    this._password = password;
    // generate salt
    this.salt = this.makeSalt();
    // encrypt password
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function () {
    return this._password;
  });

// methods > authenticate, encryptPassword, makeSalt
userSchema.methods = {
  authenticate: function (plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) == this.hashed_password;
  },
  encryptPassword: function (password) {
    if (!password) return "";
    try {
      return crypto
        .createHmac("sha1", this.salt)
        .update(password)
        .digest("hex");
    } catch (err) {
      return "";
    }
  },
  makeSalt: function () {
    return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random()) + "";
  },
};

// export user model
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The error it throws is
throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${val}` is not ` +
^

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `` is not a valid type at path `default`. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition for a list of valid schema types.

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I've looked over the new schema on the docs, but can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is related to the schema definition in your Mongoose model. Specifically, the error message suggests that there is an issue with the default value provided for the resetPasswordLink field.

To fix the error, make sure you provide a valid default value for the resetPasswordLink field. The default value should match the specified type, which is String in this case.

```js
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    // Other fields...
    resetPasswordLink: {
      data: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

In the updated code, the resetPasswordLink field is defined as an object with a data property of type String and a default value of an empty string ("").

Make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed (mongoose, crypto) and the Mongoose connection is properly established before using this model.

Comment: Thank you. So frustrating that little issue was the cause